# ORLite: Unicode-question

Tags: perl, sqlite, unicode, model, mojolicious

Where is the right place to put the `sqlite_unicode` setting when using [ORLite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ORLite)?

Comment: Back to my liking: as few layers as possible.

Comment: `possible` not in the strict sense of the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a really good place.  See [bug #61191: Enable sqllite_unicode in the `DBI->connect` attrs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=61191) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

[From now on](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ADAMK/ORLite-1.52/Changes), you can just use the `unicode` option, which will set `sqlite_unicode` for you. [Fixed in 1.52](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ADAMK/ORLite-1.52/Changes). :-)

```
use ORLite {
    file    => 'sample.db',
    unicode => 1,
    ...
```